# Quoridor AI - undirected graph

Tags: prolog

As a homework, I need to create an AI for the game Quoridor.

[image: normal board]

After some analysis on my side, I decided to represent the board of the game as an undirected graph (see below).

[image: undirected graph]

The idea is to find the shortest path for each pawn to his objective and it's easier to do with such representation I guess...

The problem is that I really don't understand how to represent such graph in Prolog. I already saw how to create simple undirected graph with like 10 edges but this one's got 81.

Example of a simple undirected graph :

```
arc(1,2).    
arc(2,1).    
arc(1,4).    
arc(4,1).    
arc(2,3).    
arc(3,2).    
arc(3,5).    
arc(5,3).    
arc(5,6).    
arc(6,5).
```

After that, I should also be easier to user the MiniMax algorithm on the graph.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

If you number your nodes 1, 2, 3, ..., 81 according to the following scheme:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
...
```

then in your graph you have arcs from 1 to 2, from 2 to 3, **not** from 3 to 4 but then again from 4 to 5, ... etc. You also have an arc from 4 to 13 but not, for example, from 5 to 14. Right?

In this way you can read off the list of arcs from the diagram to get:

```
arc(1, 2).
arc(2, 3).
arc(4, 5).
...
arc(4, 15).
...
```

Comment: I get that yes, but then again, there is no other way than just typing the relations "by hand" until you get all the nodes right ? :( Thanks for your answer !

Comment: You don't need to number nodes like this, you could also use coordinates: `arc(node(1, 1), node(1, 2)). arc(node(1, 2), node(2, 3)). ...` Give this a try and edit your question if you run into trouble. You could also write a parser that takes some sort of representation of the graph, like `+-+-+ +-+-+...`, and generates the `arc` facts from it. Open a new question if you run into trouble.